# Lua coexist in baremetal embedded c application

Tags: lua, embedded

I'm investigating if it is possible to make lua  coexist with my real time embedded application. I want to use lua so the customer can make custom commands in the application. All the I/O is done by the main application.So lua only needs to communicate with the main C application. As far as I understand, that is not a problem. 
I'm thinking of that the main application generates an event and then a custom lua application is started.

How do I prevent it to use all the cpu time, for example in an endless loop. how do I solve that? (timeout error or something)
And is it possible to reduce the code size of the lualib?

Thanks,
 EVS

Answer (score 3):

> How do I prevent it to use all the cpu time, for example in an endless loop. how do I solve that? (timeout error or something)

Run the Lua process at the lowest possible thread priority so that if the user code has "*busy-loops*" it may be preempted by any other thread.  If you have other threads at the same priority, you will need to ensure that time-slicing is enabled in the scheduler if possible.

You might also implement a Lua process watchdog - a higher priority task that monitors the activity of the Lua process and can terminate it if it busy-waits.  This can be implemented without changing Lua in any way by incrementing a counter in the idle-task loop, and arranging task priorities as follows:

```
 -----------------
| All other tasks |
|      ...        |
|-----------------|
| Lua watchdog    |
|-----------------|
| Lua             |
|-----------------|
| Idle            |
 -----------------
```

If the Lua watchdog observes the Idle counter stops increment for an excessive period, then the Lua process is stalled and the watchdog must take corrective action - killing the Lua process/thread, recovering resources or issuing a warning message perhaps.

> And is it possible to reduce the code size of the lualib?

Consider using [eLua](http://www.eluaproject.net/) rather than porting Desktop Lua yourself, then consider the techniques described in the [NodeMCU project FAQ](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/lua-developer-faq/#techniques-for-reducing-ram-and-spiffs-footprint).